# http://localhost:3000/users/new Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im following this tutorial. http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/ i just the part titled **Adding Some Validations to the User Model**

When i go to http://localhost:3000/users/new i get an routing error. But based on my knowledge the rout looks fine. Whats wrong?

[image]

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'
```

Model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: It should work; can you paste the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: sorry i just added the error to post then.

Comment: Rename user_controller.rb to users_controller.rb.

Comment: $ rake routes
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
   Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
users_new GET  /users/new(.:format) users#new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your file implementing `UsersController` to `users_controller.rb`.

Also, your regexp `EMAIL_REGEX` in `User` class causes an error. You should modify it as error says:

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
```

Comment: I just did that. Error is

ArgumentError in UsersController#new

The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Comment: Sounds like you have dodgy regexen in your model, @joeyk16

Comment: I just added the user.rb model to my question

Comment: That fixed it but more errors now. Pretty sure now that the tutorial is wrong. More errors.

No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}

Comment: it worked.

Use this in routes.   get 'users/new'

get ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'